# golang regular expression to extract pairs of quantities and their units

Tags: regex, go

I have a set of human readable strings expressing a duration of time.  Here are four examples:

```
1 days 40 hrs 23 min 50 sec

3 hrs 1 min 30 sec

10 days 23 min 11 sec

52 sec
```

I am trying to convert these strings into number of seconds.  The math to do this is quite simple once the string is broken down into its components - it's just multiplication and addition.  I am having some issues however with writing the regular expression to parse the string into `[<quantity>, <unit>]` pairs.  As an example, the output I would like for the string:

`1 days 40 hrs 23 min 50 sec`

is an array (or slice) like:

`[[1, "days"], [40, "hrs"], [23, "min"], [50, "sec"]]`.

Below is the code for what I've tried so far and its output (executable at http://play.golang.org/p/iR-xfc8MVQ).  `segs` was my first attempt, which seems to break the string down into 4 components ok but each component is just a string like `1 days` rather than a 2-element array like `[1, days]`.  `segs2` was my second attempt, which seems to do something weirder where each component is repeated twice.

```
// time unit tokenizer
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {
    s := "1 days 40 hrs 23 min 50 sec"
    re := regexp.MustCompile("(?P<quant>\\d+) (?P<unit>\\w+)+")

    segs := re.FindAllString(s, -1)
    fmt.Println("segs:", segs)
    fmt.Println(segs[0], "," ,segs[1], ",", segs[2], ",", segs[3])  
    fmt.Println("length segs:", len(segs))

    segs2 := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(s, -1)
    fmt.Println("segs2:", segs2)
    fmt.Println(segs2[0], "," ,segs2[1], ",", segs2[2], ",", segs2[3])
    fmt.Println("length segs2:", len(segs2))
}
```

Output:

```
segs: [1 days 40 hrs 23 min 50 sec]
1 days , 40 hrs , 23 min , 50 sec
length segs: 4
segs2: [[1 days 1 days] [40 hrs 40 hrs] [23 min 23 min] [50 sec 50 sec]]
[1 days 1 days] , [40 hrs 40 hrs] , [23 min 23 min] , [50 sec 50 sec]
length segs2: 4
```

I've written a similar regex is Python which works OK, so I'm really not sure whether I am doing something incorrect for Go's regular expression syntax or perhaps making the wrong call on the `re` object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch`](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch) returns `[][]string`. But its contents are slightly different from the return value of the Python function [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) (I assumed that you used `re.findall` in Python).

- **`return_value[i][0]` contains whole matched string.**
- `return_value[i][1]` contains captured group 1.
- `return_value[i][2]` contains captured group 2. ....

Printing `return_value[i]` cause all items in `return_value[i]` to be printed. (`return_value[i][0]`, `return_value[i][1]`, `return_value[i][2]`, ..)

---

You can get what you expected by only printing captured group matches (excluding `[0]`) as follow:

```
segs2 := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(s, -1)
for i := 0; i < len(segs2); i++ {
    fmt.Println(segs2[i][1], "," ,segs2[i][2]);
}
```

[Demo](http://play.golang.org/p/kfdhI68C4l)

---

**Side Note**

Following string literal:

```
"(?P<quant>\\d+) (?P<unit>\\w+)+"
```

can be expressed as the following raw string literals.

```
`(?P<quant>\d+) (?P<unit>\w+)+`
```

See [String literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals)

Comment: Spot on - I had been using `re.findall` in Python and had been expecting similar behavior.